# How can I pick coordinate from Google map in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, maps

I have an application where I used Google map. I want to pick coordinates from the map.

Can anybody tell how can I pick coordinate from Google map in rails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is for you:

https://github.com/railscash/gmap_coordinates_picker

Please see the documentation for more details